# Acceder a contenido de Div tras actualizacion por via Ajax

Tags: ajax

Buen dia a todos,

Tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una peticion Ajax en donde recargo el contenido de un Div y en el pongo la respuesta, pero necesito acceder a la respuesta que se ha recargado con una funcion jquery, este archivo se encuentra enlazado a mi proyecto, pero no ejecuta la funcion que necesito al momento que se recargo el div.

Codigo de Funcion que actualiza el Div

---

$('#maker').on("change", function () {

```
    if ($(this).val() == 0){
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '?c=index&m=queryAllReferences',
           data: null
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#responseQueryReferenceForMaker').load( response);
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '?c=index&m=queryReferenceForMaker',
           data: {value: $(this).val()}
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#responseQueryReferenceForMaker').html(response);
        });
    }
});
```

---

Codigo de la funcion en el que tomo la info del div actualizado

---

$('#reference').on("change", function () {

```
    alert($(this).val());
    /*if($(this).val() == 0){
        alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '?c=index&m=queryFunctionForReferenceDefault',
           data: null
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#resultQueryOnlyFunction').html(response);
        });
   } else {
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '?c=index&m=queryFunctionForReferenceIndexController',
           data: {valueReference : $('#reference').val()}
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#resultQueryOnlyFunction').html(response);
        });
   }*/
});
```

Comment: no se entiende bien que es lo que necesitas hacer al obtener el callback?

Comment: La función on de jquery funciona sobre un selector padre, es decir $("elemento padre").on('change', "elemento ligado al evento", funcion)

Comment: Hola Brahian, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español.  Por ser nuevo en el sitio es normal que no sepas las mejores practicas para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.  Una muy importante es no poner fotos de tu codigo, sino copiar y pagar el texto para que sea mas facil de ver y reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Por cierto, acabo de responder una pregunta muy similar a la tuya: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/porque-no-se-ejecuta-mi-funci%C3%B3n-js-con-elementos-select-que-creo-diat%C3%B3nicamente

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quiero es tomar la informacion de un div que actualize con ajax.

Ya edite la pregunta, gracias por lo de no subir imagenes.